# What are the proper steps to create an encrypted java chat server/client?

Tags: java, encryption, java-server

I have been searching the web and here on how to create an encrypted chat server/client. And I think I got pretty confused now.

Firstly, I created a chat server/client from the free example **Knock Knock Server** from the `Java Examples`. So far, everything is working nicely, until I want to encrypt both server and clients.

Secondly, where do I start the encryption first? From the server then to the client? Am I suppose to use that `Java Tool` to create an encryption file for the server and share it with the clients?

Lastly, I am so confused after looking at so many tutorials on encryption, I don't know what is best for my situation. Can anyone help direct me to the correct tutorial website? Thanks a lot.

P.S. I do not know what kind of **encryption tag** I am suppose to use. Please edit that for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you read about [Transport Layer Security](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) (**TLS**); It is *probably* the simplest reasonable approach to security and has been widely adopted (e.g. https and ftps).

In a sentence, it works by establishing a "secure channel" for your existing protocol to communicate over.

[image: TLS/SSL Handshake Protocol]

Comment: I read about that already. What I want to know would be, where do I start using the encryption and how do I share the private/public key to the client?

Comment: @MelvinLai During "key exchange" as documented in the above link. I edited my answer to include the 10 step TLS/SSL handshake protocol.

Comment: Wow, now that is something I didn't see. Worth the read now. Thanks. BTW, where did you find this info from?

Comment: Image search "tls handshake protocol".

Comment: Thank you. I will proceed from there, and that site looks like it will give me the solution.

Answer (score 1):

i don't think you need encryption and another tools. just use `jsr-356` for websocket based chatting and `ssl` for securing your content.

Comment: Sorry, I do need the encryption.